# How to send a form to parent component

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactiveForm that I want to send the values in the form to the parent component that contains the the submit button and it need to be able to handle the (`ngSumbmit)` in the form. If it'not possible to accomplish what I want I will just add the button inside of the `form`.

**HTML**-child component

```
  <form class="credit-card-form" [formGroup]="creditCardForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitPayment()">
    <div class="credit-card-form-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <label class="x-field-label x-top-aligned-field-label label-top-inputs">Cardholder Name</label>
        <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="cardHolderName" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label class="x-field-label x-top-aligned-field-label label-top-inputs">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="companyName" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label class="x-field-label x-top-aligned-field-label label-top-inputs">Credit Card # <i>(Accepting VISA, Mastercard,
            AmEX)
          </i></label>
        <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="CCNumber" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**TS**

```
  creditCardForm = this.fb.group({
    cardHolderName: ['', Validators.required],
    companyName: ['', Validators.required],
    CCNumber: ['', Validators.required],
  });
```

**HTML**- parent component

```
<div class="pay-storage-container">
  <div class="pay-storage-inner">
    <app-credit-card></app-credit-card>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <button pButton type="button" label="Submit Payment" class="x-primary-green-400"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One way would be to send data to parent component would be via Output.

Comment: Yeah I know it can be done via Output but by using Output will need a EventEmmiter...how can I use an Output if I don't have a button?

Comment: Why do you need to send the form or it's values to the parent component? When the submit button is clicked in the parent component, you can just access the child component and it's form values.

Comment: @Himanshu I need to send it because the submit button is in the parent component. I can use ViewChild, correct?

Comment: Yes! Use the `ViewChild` to access the child component. When submit button is clicked in the parent component, you can access the form values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can like this,

here's is an example

in `child.component.html`

```
<form class="credit-card-form" [formGroup]="creditCardForm">
    <div class="credit-card-form-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="x-field-label x-top-aligned-field-label label-top-inputs">Cardholder Name</label>
            <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="cardHolderName" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="x-field-label x-top-aligned-field-label label-top-inputs">Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="companyName" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="x-field-label x-top-aligned-field-label label-top-inputs">Credit Card # <i>(Accepting VISA, Mastercard,
            AmEX)
          </i></label>
            <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="CCNumber" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in `child.component.ts`

```
creditCardForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.creditCardForm = this.fb.group({
      cardHolderName: ['', Validators.required],
      companyName: ['', Validators.required],
      CCNumber: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

and in `parent.component.html`

```
<div class="pay-storage-container">
    <div class="pay-storage-inner">
        <app-child #child></app-child>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-container">
        <button pButton type="button" label="Submit Payment" class="x-primary-green-400" (click)="onSubmitPayment()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

`parent.component.ts`

```
@ViewChild('child') childCompopnent: any;

  ngOnInit(){ }

  onSubmitPayment(){
    console.log(this.childCompopnent.creditCardForm.value);
  }
```

here's [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijtsfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo

Comment: You are right. I literally figured it out myself 5 minutes ago, but I'm still going to give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing i couldn't figured it out is that if I have a the disabled directive in the submit button to check if the form is valid or not, it still remains as invalid. I have this in my ngOnit() of my parent component `this.validCCFrom = this.creditCardFormGroup.creditCardForm.valid;`

Comment: Why not pass as Input the creditCardForm? (the creditCardform belong to parent). I feel that is more natural way.

Comment: @TamoDev you can check form is valid or not like this way... <button [disabled]="child.creditCardForm.invalid">Submit</button>.. i have updated demo as well

Comment: @Eliseo there are so many ways to do this but as per 'TamoDev'  requirements this is the only way.

Comment: This is not the angular way, and a bad pattern in regular js. It should use the ngSubmit binding, and use an event emitter from the child component to the parent following the smart/dumb component architecture. all logic should be in the parent.

Comment: I am not sure how are you able to write `@ViewChild('child') childCompopnent: any;` this line code in parent component. I see `childComponent` define no where. Its actual `ChildComponent` but still you did not import the file. Help me understand this.

Comment: @Santosh `ChildComponent` is not the actual component, it's the variable name of `@ViewChild('child')`. As i am using template reference variable to access all the properties from child component, You don't need to import `ChildComponent`.